# MS Access- How can I open a Ole Object in a form?

Tags: object, ms-access, ole, ms-access-2003

I am a complete novice at access and I've got a table with all employee training records and a Attachment Field where I  have been attaching the employee certificates (Ole Object) and in the table it opens the PDF fine. However I have a datasheet form and the Ole object wont open. How can I change it so it will open on click (just like in the table)?

Comment: Clarerome: Is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set the [Autoactivate property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845520.aspx) of the OLE object in your form to **Double-click**. Right-click or double-click the control in design view to open the properties dialogue.